# lifecycleScope.launch vs coroutine inside onViewCreated

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

In this example code:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment {
    init {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            whenStarted {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

the code inside whenStarted only gets run when the fragment's lifecycle starts. It isn't clear to me though what exactly this does instead of just launching a coroutine inside of onViewCreated. The docs state:

> If the Lifecycle is destroyed while a coroutine is active via one of
>   the when methods, the coroutine is automatically canceled.

So is that the only reason why you would use lifecycleScope.launch? To have the coroutine automatically terminated if the lifecycle gets terminated?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`lifecycleScope` is a scope that is managed by a `SupervisorJob` whose lifecycle is tied to the `Fragment`'s lifecycle. So just by using `lifecycleScope` your coroutines will be cancelled when the underlying `Lifecycle` instance  (the `Fragment`'s `LifecycleRegistry` in this case)  is destroyed.

I believe that
`lifecycleScope.launch { whenStarted {}}` is the more verbose form of `lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {}`. As you would expect, the lambda passed into `launchWhenStarted` will suspend until the `Fragment` is on the started state.

> So is that the only reason why you would use lifecycleScope.launch? To
>   have the coroutine automatically terminated if the lifecycle gets
>   terminated?

Cancellation is one of the benefits. Another benefit is that `lifecycleScope.launch` uses the `MainDispatcher` by default (unlike other builders which use `Dispatches.Default` by default), so it guarantees that coroutines launched with it can perform UI operations.